# Excel File - How to extract multiple keys and make them as columns and value separated by ':' as row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I am reading an Excel(xlsx) with columns Number and Info where Info contains plain multiline keys:values.
I want to extract the specific keys(from the list of keys) and make them as new columns.

```
List of Keys = [Name, Age, Gender, Occupation]
```

Tricky part is at few places keys have been mentioned differently like Name/Full Name, Gender/Sex. Sequence is not fixed and if key is not available thn leave the value cell as blank.

I am using pandas to achieve this. Any help is appreciated here.

[image]

Comment: What format are you using: CSV or XLSX?

Comment: @PiggyPlex Its XLSX

Answer (score 1):

First read from Excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx')
```

Then iterate over each row and parse what you want. Below is an Example:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    info = row[1]["info"].split('\n')
    name = info[0].split(": ")[1]
    age = info[1].split(": ")[1]
```

At the end, you can make df with these parsed values and save as xlsx, etc.

**Edit**

If you want to parse unordered info, this code may help you:

```
listOfKeys = {"Name", "Age", "Gender", "Occupation"}
for row in df.iterrows():
    #   Separate each items
    info = row[1]["info"].split('\n')
    #   Remove unwanted spaces
    info = [item.replace(" ", "") for item in info]
    
    items = {item.split(":")[0]: item.split(":")[1] for item in info}

    emptyKeys = listOfKeys - set(items.keys())

    for emptyKey in emptyKeys:
        items[emptyKey] = ""
```

So, each info convert to a dict named items above and all non-given features have empty value.

Comment: Hi Salimi, thanks a lot for the answer but the problem is keys:values might not be in the same sequence so i am looking for more of dynamic solution where will search for those keys which are available in the list and if its not available thn value cell will be kept as empty.